# Is there a decent online-based wire-framing app for UX developers?

Tags: wireframe

Other than Basalmiq or Omnigraffle, I'm looking for something that will allow full online sharing and team editing with the ability to comment. Is there anything available as open source or paid subscription? I'm thinking along the similarities of InvisionApp, if anyone is familiar with that.

Comment: Have you tried Axure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [UXPin](http://www.uxpin.com/).